# Convert number to date in sql and fetch the data from the daily date

Tags: sql, oracle

I hope everyone well,

Anyone can help me to fetch the daily date data , my table look like

[image]

any help for this will be so appreciated.

Thank you so much

Comment: timestamp column is number ?

Comment: yes , so for example the daily today  will be like this 20211119133511

Answer (score 1):

Use `TO_DATE`:

```sql
SELECT book,
       library,
       TO_DATE(timestamp, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') AS timestamp,
       count
FROM   my_table
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table (book, library, timestamp, count) AS
SELECT 'History',  'Alexandra', 20200110133752, 32 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'action',   'Liba',      20200112133752, 44 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Learning', 'PML',       20200113133752, 53 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs (with the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` as `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS`):

> | BOOK | LIBRARY | TIMESTAMP | COUNT |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | History | Alexandra | 2020-01-10 13:37:52 | 32 |
> | action | Liba | 2020-01-12 13:37:52 | 44 |
> | Learning | PML | 2020-01-13 13:37:52 | 53 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ca7e18ca3e6d737aa1055f700052fe43)*

Comment: this is perfect is working